# Server response time not decreasing

Tags: performance, wampserver, connectivity, server-response

I am using [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) to test my website (home page | ~0.6Mo) currently hosted on my computer (wampserver on windows) and PageSpeed indicates that my server response time is high (0.6s to 1.2s).

I tested the home page of some website I hosted on [Hostinger.fr](http://www.hostinger.fr/) long time ago (I was a newbie back then and I had no idea how important response time was | ~2.6Mo for the home page), and PageSpeed found that the response time was cool (less than 0.4s I think).

I did every thing I could but nothing works, my response time keeps varying between 0.6s and 1.2s randomly. Could it be because of my Internet connectivity (420Ko/s at its peak) or because of my computer performance (3.1Ghz Pentium 4 | 2.5Go RAM)?

Comment: If the website you're visiting is hosted on your local machine, your internet connectivity has nothing to do with it - unless you're pulling down externally-hosted resources. (Like jQuery, Google Fonts, etc.)

Comment: @CraigOtis Hi, I am not pulling any externally-hosted resources. Does that mean that my computer performance could be the cause? Will the response time decrease to less than 0.4s if I host my website on hostinger or any other company?

Comment: It's hard to say. 0.4 seconds isn't bad. Neither is 0.6 seconds, or 1.2 seconds. It's all relative to what you're loading. Google (just the home page) takes about 1 second to finish all the network requests. The Verge, even with the Disconnect plugin, takes about 1.8 seconds. Engadget takes 3-4 seconds. Are you loading text? Pictures? Flash?

Comment: I am loading text and pictures in my home page i even loaded css by including the content of css files in the style elements using php, same goes for javascript and jquery libraries. Also I enabled compression on all types of files in my htaccess file.